# How do I get the posts from single page custom post type from a sidebar to display in a page?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a custom post type called storylist, which is done as a plugin for a sidebar widget.The custom post type story list compiles lists of other custom post types and displays them in the sidebar. The same way the posts are displaying in the sidebar, I need to have that same list, which in this case is "hot topics" display on a page when the "view more" button is clicked. The best I got was an archive of all the storylist posts but when you click on them, such as hot topics, it take you to the url http://site/storylist/hot-topics , which is the correct url, but it's blank and only shows the title of the page. Any suggestions on how to make those posts appear on hot topics?

Here's the code to make it display in the widget:

```
              <?php

             // Prevent loading this file directly
            defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;


    class ChemTabs extends WP_Widget {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(
        'tabs', _('Tabs Widget'),
        array(
            'description' => _('A tabs widget.'),
        ));
}

private function ce_getPostClass($style, $index) {
    switch ($style) {
        case 'first-up':
            if ( $index == 0 ) return 'first-up';
            else return 'list-type';
            break;
        default:
            return $style;
    }
}

private function ce_has($listStyle, $index, $post) {
    $class = $this->ce_getPostClass($listStyle, $index);

    $has = array(
        'thumb'         => false,
        'terms'         => true,
        'date'          => true,
        'content'       => false,
        'excerpt'       => false,
        'title'         => true,
        'video'         => false,
        'webinarDate'   => false
    );
    switch ($class) {
        case 'first-up':
            $has['thumb'] = true;
            $has['excerpt'] = true;
            break;
        case 'list-type':
            $has['terms'] = false;
            break;
        case 'thumblist':
            $has['thumb'] = true;
            break;
        case 'single': // no need for this anymore probably
            $has['content'] = true;
            break;
    }

    switch ($post->post_type) {
        case 'video':
            $has['video'] = true;
            break;
        case 'webinar':
            $has['webinarDate'] = true;
            break;
    }
    return $has;
}

public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    global $post;

    $instance['tab_1_title']    = isset($instance['tab_1_title'])?$instance['tab_1_title']:'Tab 1';
    $instance['tab_2_title']    = isset($instance['tab_2_title'])?$instance['tab_2_title']:'Tab 2';

    $instance['storylist_id_1'] = isset($instance['storylist_id_1']) ? $instance['storylist_id_1'] : '';
    $instance['storylist_id_2'] = isset($instance['storylist_id_2']) ? $instance['storylist_id_2'] : '';

    $instance['n']              = isset($instance['n']) ? $instance['n'] : 4;

    $title      = isset($instance['title'])?$instance['title']:'';
    $type       = isset($instance['type'])?$instance['type']:'color';
    $class      = isset($instance['class'])?$instance['class']:'brand-primary';

    // Post list configuration
    // Note: posts temporarily rendered with ajax
    $list_style     = isset($instance['listStyle'])?$instance['listStyle']:'thumblist';
    $list_post_type = isset($instance['post_type'])?$instance['post_type']:'post';
    $list_filter    = isset($instance['filter'])?$instance['filter']:'{}';
    $list_display   = isset($instance['display'])?$instance['display']:5;
    $list_channel   = isset($instance['channel'])?$instance['channel']:0;
    $list_division  = isset($instance['division'])?$instance['division']:0;
    $readmore       = isset($instance['readmore'])?$instance['readmore'] : '';

    $list_args1 = array( "post_type" => "any", "post__in" => get_post_meta($instance['storylist_id_1'], 'storylist', true), "orderby" => "post__in" );
    $posts1 = new WP_Query();
    $posts1 = $posts1->query($list_args1);

    $list_args2 = array( "post_type" => "any", "post__in" => get_post_meta($instance['storylist_id_2'], 'storylist', true), "orderby" => "post__in" );
    $posts2 = new WP_Query();
    $posts2 = $posts2->query($list_args2);              

    // Note: posts temporarily rendered with ajax
    echo $args['before_widget'];

    $instance['tab_2_title'] = get_the_title($instance['storylist_id_2']);

    //@TODO: Use get_template_part('content/post', $modifier); on tabs too.
    ?>
    <div class="module tabs">

        <div class="striped striped-gray">
            <!-- Nav tabs -->
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#tab-pane-1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                        <h2 class="h4"><?= $instance['tab_1_title'] ?></h2>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#tab-pane-2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                        <h2 class="h4"><?= $instance['tab_2_title'] ?></h2>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <!-- Tab panes -->
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-pane-1">
                    <div class="post-list no-c-paginator" max="<?= $instance['n'] ?>">
                        <?php
                        $n = 0;
                        foreach((array)$posts1 as $post): setup_postdata($post);
                            $n++;
                            if ( $n % 3 == 1) {
                                ?> <div class="no-c-container<?php echo $n == 1 ? ' active' : '';?>"> <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                            <article class="article thumblist no-c-paginator-item">
                                <!-- thumbnail -->
                                <?php echo the_post_thumbnail('cm_thumb', array('class' => 'img-thumbnail pull-left', 'style' => 'margin-right: 0.5em;')) ?>

                                <header>
                                    <!-- terms -->
                                    <?php if (!empty($terms) ): ?>
                                        <p class="terms">
                                            <a href="<?= $terms[0]['link'] ?>"><?= $terms[0]['name'] ?></a>
                                        </p>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <!-- title -->
                                    <h3 class="title"><a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo apply_filters('the_title', the_title()); ?></a></h3>

                                    <!-- Time -->
                                    <div class="date-author">
                                        <?php include(locate_template('UI/byline.php')); ?>
                                        <span class="topic"><?php echo cm_get_single_topic() ?></span>
                                    </div>
                                </header>

                                <div class="clearfix"></div><!-- to clear the thumbnail's left floating -->
                            </article>
                            <?php

                        if ( $n % 3 == 0) {
                            ?> </div> <?php
                        }
                        endforeach; wp_reset_postdata();
                        if ( $n % 3 != 0) {
                                ?> </div> <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                        <?php if($readmore): ?>
                            <div class="actions">
                                <button href="<?php echo $readmore; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">View More</button>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="actions">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary prev-item" disabled="disabled"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left"></i> Prev</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary next-item">Next <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-pane-2">
                    <div class="post-list no-c-paginator" max="<?= $instance['n'] ?>">
                        <?php
                        $n = 0;
                        foreach((array)$posts2 as $post):
                            $n++;
                            if ( $n % 3 == 1) {
                                ?> <div class="no-c-container<?php echo $n == 1 ? ' active' : '';?> "> <?php
                            }

                            ?>
                            <article class="article thumblist no-c-paginator-item">
                                <!-- thumbnail -->
                                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'cm_thumb', array('class' => 'img-thumbnail pull-left', 'style' => 'margin-right: 0.5em;')) ?>

                                <header>
                                    <!-- terms -->
                                    <?php if (!empty($terms) ): ?>
                                        <p class="terms">
                                            <a href="<?= $terms[0]['link'] ?>"><?= $terms[0]['name'] ?></a>
                                        </p>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <!-- title -->
                                    <h3 class="title"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"><?php echo apply_filters('the_title', $post->post_title); ?></a></h3>

                                    <!-- Time -->
                                    <div class="date-author">
                                        <time datetime="<?php the_time('c'); ?>" pubdate="pubdate" ><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></time>
                                        <?php include(locate_template('UI/byline.php')); ?>
                                        <span class="topic"><?php echo cm_get_single_topic() ?></span>
                                    </div>
                                </header>

                                <div class="clearfix"></div><!-- to clear the thumbnail's left floating -->
                            </article>
                        <?php
                        if ( $n % 3 == 0) {
                            ?> </div> <?php
                        }
                        endforeach;

                        if ( $n % 3 != 0) {
                            ?> </div> <?php
                        }


                        ?>


                        <?php //if($readmore): ?>
                            <div class="actions">
                                <a href="<?php echo CFS()->get('view_more_link', 210639); ?>" class="btn btn-primary">View More</a>
                            </div>
                        <?php //endif; ?>

                        <!--<div class="actions">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary prev-item" disabled="disabled"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left"></i> Prev</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary next-item">Next <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button>
                        </div>-->

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
    echo $args['after_widget'];
}

public function form( $instance ) {
    $instance['tab_1_title']    = isset($instance['tab_1_title'])?$instance['tab_1_title']:'Tab 1';
    $instance['tab_2_title']    = isset($instance['tab_2_title'])?$instance['tab_2_title']:'Tab 2';
    $instance['n']              = isset($instance['n'])?$instance['n']:4;

    $sl_posts = get_posts(array(
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'post_type'         => 'storylist'
    ));
    ?>
    <h5>Tab 1</h5>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'tab_1_title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'tab_1_title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'tab_1_title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $instance['tab_1_title'] ); ?>">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'storylist_id_1' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Story List:' ); ?></label>
        <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'storylist_id_1' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'storylist_id_1' ); ?>">
            <?php
            if (count($sl_posts)) {
                foreach($sl_posts as $storyList) {
                    $selected = ($instance['storylist_id_1'] == $storyList->ID ? "selected='selected'" : "");
                    echo "<option value='{$storyList->ID}' {$selected}>{$storyList->post_title}</option>";
                }
            } else {
                echo "<option value='0'>"._('No Story Lists Found')."</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </p>
    <!-- Number of items to show -->
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'n' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Number of items to show at once:' ); ?></label>
        <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'n' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'n' ); ?>" type="number" min="0" step="1" value="<?php echo intval($instance['n']) ?>">
    </p>

    <h5>Tab 2</h5>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'tab_2_title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'tab_2_title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'tab_2_title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $instance['tab_2_title'] ); ?>">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'storylist_id_2' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Story List:' ); ?></label>
        <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'storylist_id_2' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'storylist_id_2' ); ?>">
            <?php
            if (count($sl_posts)) {
                foreach($sl_posts as $storyList) {
                    $selected = ($instance['storylist_id_2'] == $storyList->ID ? "selected='selected'" : "");
                    echo "<option value='{$storyList->ID}' {$selected}>{$storyList->post_title}</option>";
                }
            } else {
                echo "<option value='0'>"._('No Story Lists Found')."</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </p>

<?php
}

public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = array();

    $instance['tab_1_title']    = isset($new_instance['tab_1_title'])?$new_instance['tab_1_title']:'Tab 1';
    $instance['tab_2_title']    = isset($new_instance['tab_2_title'])?$new_instance['tab_2_title']:'Tab 2';

    $instance['storylist_id_1'] = isset($new_instance['storylist_id_1']) ? (int)$new_instance['storylist_id_1'] : 0;
    $instance['storylist_id_2'] = isset($new_instance['storylist_id_2']) ? (int)$new_instance['storylist_id_2'] : 0;

    $instance['n'] = isset($new_instance['n']) ? (int)$new_instance['n'] : 4;

    return $instance;
   }
 }

  add_action( 'widgets_init', function(){ register_widget( 'ChemTabs' ); });
```

Is there any way I can make a page template displaying the page id? I tried to do that but it didn't display anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding this code `$list_args2 = array( "post_type" => "any", "post__in" => get_post_meta( 210639, 'storylist', true), "orderby" => "post__in", 'post_status' => 'publish' );`